# D3.js binding an object to data and appending for each key

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-binding, interpolation

I'm a D3.js newbie and I'm learning how to play around with data.

Let's say I have an object with names as keys, and each key has an array of numbers like this:

```
var userdata = {
    'John' : [0, 1, 3, 9, 8, 7],
    'Harry': [0, 10, 7, 1, 1, 11],
    'Steve': [3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 17],
    'Adam' : [4, 77, 2, 13, 11, 13]
};
```

For each user, I would like to append an SVG object and then plot the line with the array of values for that user.

So here is my assumption of how that would look based on tutorials, but I know it is incorrect. This is to show my limited knowledge and give better understanding of what I'm doing:

First I should create the line

```
var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate('basis');
```

Then I want to bind the data to my body and append an svg element for each key:

```
d3.select('body')
    .selectAll('svg')
    .data(userdata)
    .enter()
    .append('svg')
    .append(line)
    .x(function(d, i) { return i; })
    .y(function(d) { return d[i]; });
```

So am I close??

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here's another example similar to mbeasley's: http://jsfiddle.net/2N2rt/15/ which adds axis, colors, and flips the chart right side up.  First, I massaged your data just a little bit.  Works the best if you have an array of values and I used keys to make getting to the `name` and `values` properties easier.

```
var data = [
    {name: 'John', values: [0,1,3,9, 8, 7]},
    {name: 'Harry', values: [0, 10, 7, 1, 1, 11]},
    {name: 'Steve', values: [3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 17]},
    {name: 'Adam', values: [4, 77, 2, 13, 11, 13]}
];
```

Generally in `d3` you set up the chart like this which determines the size of the actual graph and the surrounding margins.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 640 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 380 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Then you can create your scales based on your data. Though you don't have to create them, they make positioning elements on the chart much easier by converting values to points. The `domain` is the min and max values that your data has, while the `range` is the min and max values of the size of your graph. Note that the `range` for the `y axis` gets reversed which puts (0,0) in the bottom left hand corner (usually 0 for the y axis is at the top).

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.values.length - 1; })])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d3.min(d.values); }),
             d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values); })])
    .range([height, 0]);
```

`d3` has a couple of features for automatically creating color scales for you. Just set it up with the keys that you want to use and the number of colors (I think there are 10 and 20 color options).

```
var color = d3.scale.category10()
    .domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key === "name"; }));
```

Here we use our scales to setup the x and y axis.  There are lots of different options for the axes. TickFormat is handy to change how the ticks look, `d3.format` has lots of different options so that you rarely have to create a custom formatter.

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.format('d'))
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");
```

Here we create a reusable function that knows how to draw a line. We'll pass each datapoint for each person into the line function later on.  Note that `d` holds the current set of values that we are graphing and `i` is the index of the current values within our original data array.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });
```

Finally we can start adding things to our chart, first creating and positioning the main svg element.

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Then appending each axis.

```
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
```

We append a group (`g`) for each person and associate the data with the group.  We'll use this data when we draw the lines. We provide a `class` so that we can style the chart later if we want to.

```
  var people = svg.selectAll(".people")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "people");
```

Then finally draw the lines for each person.

```
  people.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

I used your data to answer another question about drawing a grid when you have negative values. You can see that graph at http://jsfiddle.net/2y3er/2/.

Comment: This is a pretty excellent example, taking the generic line generation that I had in my example quite a bit further to create a fully stylized chart.  Nice work!

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you change the layout of my object. Instead, you have an array of 4 objects whereas I have an object with 4 properties. I watched a video shortly after posting this question (http://vimeo.com/35005701) and it talks about always putting my data this way. I guess I will need to redo how my function works.

Comment: Also, thanks a lot @Bill. You have now answered 2 of my D3.js questions! See you again soon!

Comment: It's always pretty easy to coerce your data into a form that will be easier to use with d3.js.  In general, you'll want to get to an array of values of some kind. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/6WXXu/1/.

Comment: @Bill - I have created a new question using the same plot here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944202/d3-js-updating-spline-with-new-data

Answer (score 12):

I'd say you're going in the right direction.  Here's what I would do (but know that there isn't just one way to do this):

```
// your user data
var userdata = {
    'John' : [0, 1, 3, 9, 8, 7],
    'Harry': [0, 10, 7, 1, 1, 11],
    'Steve': [3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 17],
    'Adam' : [4, 77, 2, 13, 11, 13]
}; 

// add your main SVG block
var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 400)
    .attr('height', 200)
    .attr('id', 'chart');

// add an SVG group element for each user
var series = svg.selectAll('g.series')
    .data(d3.keys(userdata))
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'series');

// create your line generator
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate('basis')
    .x(function(d, i) {
        return i*40; // *40 just to increase the chart size
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return d*3; // *3 for the same reason
    });

// add a line for each user using your SVG grouping 
var lineSVG = series.selectAll('.line')
    .data(d3.keys(userdata))
    .enter()
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
        return line(userdata[d]);  
    })
    .attr('class','line');
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mbeasley183/TLPxf/) of the above code.

I also highly recommend that you read [this article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/), as it really helps solidify the way that d3 works.

Comment: thanks for the article, it seems like a lot of people recommend everyone read that article.