# D3.js updating spline with new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to update a spline with new data, but I'm running into a problem using D3.js library.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2N2rt/22/

When a user clicks the button, the goal is to have each spline animate according to the new data. I feel like I'm really close. I have read the article 'Thinking with Joins' and used it to come up with the fiddle above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle, you're applying the *d* attribute to the wrong element when changing the data.  In the *enter* group, you add a new group (class people), then add a line element to the group.  As such, when the data changes, you need to update the line within the group, not the group itself. To fix it, use

```
people.selectAll(".line").transition()
```

instead of

```
people.transition()
```

Comment: That `select` needs to be `selectAll` in order to select all of the lines.

Comment: d'oh - good point- will update the answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/3UkKW/4/.  As logical Chimp answered, you've selected the wrong elements to update.

```
var draw = function() {

    var people = svg.selectAll(".line")
        .data(data, function(d) { return d.name; });

    people
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values);});

    people.enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values);})
        .style("stroke", function(d) {return color(d.name);});

    people.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(100)
        .remove()
}
```

Comment: Hmmm - with your answer, you no longer insert the groups that contain the lines - probably doesn't make any significant difference, mind...

Comment: Yeah, they weren't actually needed. I helped with the previous iteration of the code and added them just to show him how to do it, but they weren't being used. They can be added back with no changes to this code.