# D3 donut chart based on seasons with fixed labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend, donut-chart

After successfully creating a few charts using D3 I'm now trying to create a legend for a map that looks like this:

[image: Example of a donut chart as a legend.]

This is a representation of the seasons troghout a year, illustrated by colours beneath fixed labels indicating each month of a year (in the image they're rounded down to months, I don't want that to happen in the donut chart I'm trying to create).

Now I thought I'd start out by following an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193) of a donut chart on the D3js page, and then add some sort of fixed labels afterwards. Before getting to that point though I find myself stuck and unable to replicate the example.

I've tried to make a concise example using Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H5r7K1CtUeAZst7NKTaa?p=preview), and I'm wondering if anyone would take a look. I've followed an approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923942/d3-js-binding-an-object-to-data-and-appending-for-each-key) to use a created object as data input, I don't see anything wrong with that yet, but maybe I'm mistaken. The error message I'm getting is as follows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined: Main.js(1494)
```

Line 1494 corresponds to line 37 on the Plunkr, reading:

```
.append(g)
```

This leads me to believe that something is going wrong when I point d3 to the data, but I'm unsure what this is. I'd appreciate a fresh pair of eyes looking of it!

Comment: This is wrong `.append(g)` its should have been `.append("g")`

Comment: Well, that's kind of anticlimactic. Thanks!

Yet when I fix that, I'm left with an empty div on the page. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

First, you forgot to change `population` after copying/pasting Bostock's example. I changed it for `dur`:

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null)
.value(function(d) {
  return d.dur
});
```

After that, I had to change your data:

```
  var data = [
{ seizoen: "lente", dur: 60 }, 
{ seizoen: "zomer", dur: 122 },
{ seizoen: "herfst", dur: 61 },
{ seizoen: "winter", dur: 122 }
];
```

Also, you forgot to use # to select the ID of the div:

```
 var svg = d3.select("#legend").append("svg")
```

Btw, your path to jquery was incorrect, and the #legend in your CSS was very little.

Now you have a donut: http://plnkr.co/edit/B2CJMN7Wy1By0jlMpkii?p=preview

Comment: Sigh, it's been a long week. Thanks for helping! I even had that 'population' part commented in my editor to change.

Comment: No worries. I don't use jquery, so I just copied the first path I found at cdnjs. Also, I changed the #legend in CSS to a fixed value in pixels, you may want to change that as well. Cheers.

Comment: Not in the actual product, but it's better in the plunkr yeah, thanks again.

Do you have any idea where to get started on adding fixed labels to this thing? A quick search on google only serves up this very question as an answer, but perhaps I'm looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed labels"?

Comment: In the example in the opening post, I see the first letters of the months (and the lines in white) as fixed labels, comparable to fixed ticks on a barchart, they need to always be the same, whilst the seasons can vary between graphs.

Comment: If that is the case, I believe the best idea is to create a donut based on the months, always with 12 slices the same size, and colouring each slice (i.e., filling the paths) according to your data, what do you think?

Comment: Basically creating a new donut graph using the months as data, yes that's what I was thinking of myself. The alternative would be to just use an image but that'd be bad for responsiveness reasons. I'm interested to see if appending a second donut chart to the same div would result in the outcome I'd like to see, I'm going to try that.

Comment: @Geraldo It worked pretty well, but for some reason the first couple of months arent showing up. Could you take a look at this plunk? http://plnkr.co/edit/uB7Y0F0oKEzmMUJxDVyO?p=preview

Comment: That is easy, Yoeri! In your `var g2` you selected all ".arc", but you already have 4 arcs. Look what I did here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jRGXu1JFC08zV9NV8OZk?p=preview

Comment: Sweet! Jij ook een prettige dag, bedankt :)

Comment: No worries! By the way, you can get rid of that `var svg2`, it doesn't seem to be useful.